# How to find the parameter $c$ of a joint density function.

Tags: probability, density-function

The question is: "Let $X$ and $Y$ have the joint density:

\begin{equation}
f(x,y)=cx(y-x)e^{-y} \tag{1}
\end{equation}
with $0 \leq X \leq Y \leq \infty$ [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tj8ri.jpg) . Find $c$.

In order to find $c$ the density function must satisfy the condition:
[double integral of the joint density function equal to 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aF7Ij.jpg)
Hence I  have tried to solve this integral but i have fund that it does not converge, therefore I can't find $c$. Could anybody help me?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't use the mathematical codes, but I hope the images can be opened.

Comment: You integrate by $0<x<\infty$, $0<y<\infty$. And the right area should be $0<x<\infty$ for outer integral and $x<y<\infty$ for inner integral. Or $0<y<\infty$ for outer, $0<x<y$ for inner.

Comment: Ok, now I try to solve the double integral with the right areas suggested by you. Thanks for the answer